# Defining profile dependant YAML properties in Spring Boot 1.4

Tags: spring-boot

When defining properties in YAML for a Spring Boot 1.4 application, I have to use the main/resources/application.yaml file. So far, so good.

How can I override these dependencies using YAML depending for a specific profile when running or testing the application.

Answer (score 0):

When using Spring Boot 1.4 (this applies for release 1.3 as well) YAML properties are always defined in the main/resources/application.yaml file. Depending on the chosen profile, the properties can be overridden by another set of properties.

To override these properties for test, a YAML file has to be given in the /test/resources/application-.yaml file, where  is replaced by the active profile. It is important to see that the profile always has to be given, even when there is no active profile. In that case, the profile is ‘default’.

To override the properties when running the application, properties can be overridden for a specific profile using in a file called main/resources/application-.yaml file. Even for this situation, if no profile is given, the profile for the filename is ‘default’.

Example

[image: Example of YAML file structure for Spring Boot]

The test class Spring14ApplicationTests.java for Spring Boot 1.4 has the following definition

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
public class Spring14ApplicationTests {
   …
}
```

For Spring Boot 1.3, the same file has the following definition

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=SpringDb14Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SpringDb14ApplicationTests {
    ...
}
```